# jprofiler 9 osx fails to start

Tags: java, macos, jprofiler

I've installed jprofiler 9 on my mac (had previous versions installed but uninstalled them first using the included un-installer).  However, it fails to start - crash report is:

> Crashed Thread:        0  AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
>      Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000030353230
>
> VM Regions Near 0x30353230:
>      -->
>          __TEXT                 0000000100000000-000000010000a000 [   40K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/JProfiler.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
>
> Application Specific Information:
>      abort() called
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>      0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff8fd30286 **pthread_kill + 10
>      1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x00007fff855999b3 abort + 129
>      2   libjvm.dylib                   0x0000000104c54beb os::abort(bool) + 25
>      3   libjvm.dylib                   0x0000000104d78a2a VMError::report_and_die() + 2304
>      4   libjvm.dylib                   0x0000000104c56816 JVM_handle_bsd_signal + 1131
>      5   libjvm.dylib                   0x0000000104c52a7b signalHandler(int, __siginfo*, void*) + 47
>      6   libsystem_platform.dylib       0x00007fff8687df1a _sigtramp + 26
>      7   libsystem_c.dylib              0x00007fff8553cfb2 strlen + 18
>      8   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff8f4d6a3c __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 8524
>      9   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff8f5cc3a0 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 256
>      10  com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff8f9e7701 -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] + 153
>      11  com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff8fa00ef9 +[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 174
>      12  com.apple.java.JavaRuntimeSupport  0x000000011ba2dcd2 -[JRSInputMethodController currentInputMethodLocale] + 124
>      13  libawt_lwawt.dylib             0x0000000123065294 __Java_sun_lwawt_macosx_CInputMethod_getNativeLocale_block_invoke_1 + 124
>      14  JavaNativeFoundation           0x000000011ba4753d +[JNFRunLoop _performDirectBlock:] + 12
>      15  com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff8fa6fdd0 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 293
>      16  com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff8f518a01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>      17  com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff8f50ab8d **CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
>      18  com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff8f50a1bf __CFRunLoopRun + 927
>      19  com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff8f509bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
>      20  com.apple.HIToolbox            0x00007fff8c28b56f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
>      21  com.apple.HIToolbox            0x00007fff8c28b2ea ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
>      22  com.apple.HIToolbox            0x00007fff8c28b12b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
>      23  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff912428ab _DPSNextEvent + 978
>      24  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff91241e58 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
>      25  libosxapp.dylib                0x000000011c41b3aa -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 124
>      26  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff91237af3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
>      27  libosxapp.dylib                0x000000011c41b14d +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:] + 156
>      28  libsplashscreen.dylib          0x000000011c3f7558 __SplashInitPlatform_block_invoke_1 + 360
>      29  JavaNativeFoundation           0x000000011ba475f5 +[JNFRunLoop _performCopiedBlock:] + 20
>      30  com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff8fa6fdd0 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 293
>      31  com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff8f518a01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>      32  com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff8f50ab8d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
>      33  com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff8f50a1bf __CFRunLoopRun + 927
>      34  com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff8f509bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
>      35  com.oracle.java.8u60.jdk       0x00000001000f38fb CreateExecutionEnvironment + 871
>      36  com.oracle.java.8u60.jdk       0x00000001000ef644 JLI_Launch + 1952
>      37  com.install4j.6171-3572-4726-1190.2    0x0000000100006fa5 -[Launcher launch] + 853
>      38  com.install4j.6171-3572-4726-1190.2    0x0000000100007649 launcher_main + 633
>      39  com.install4j.6171-3572-4726-1190.2    0x00000001000077b2 main + 34
>      40  com.install4j.6171-3572-4726-1190.2    0x0000000100001d34 start + 52

suggestions please (that don't involve upgrade to El Capitan / full os re-install...).

TIA
Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual bug is in the JavaRuntimeSupport (JRS) library provided by Apple since version 10.6. It is fixed in 10.11. As a workaround for 10.10 and earlier versions, install Apple's latest legacy Java 6 package (https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) which ships a fixed version of JRS.

See

http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2015/Sep/msg00006.html

for the discussion on the Apple mailing list.

Comment: This also helped me with the crash of  DBVisualizer 9.5